# How to send the Escape Key inside VirtualBox "vi" session?

Tags: virtualbox, keyboard-shortcuts, vi

When using a "vi" session within VirtualBox,  how can I send the Escape Key to change modes from input mode to command mode?   I have tried many combinations which do not work:  Ctrl-Esc, Atl-Esc,  Shift-Esc,  Alt-Ctrl-Esc, Shift-Ctrl-Esc, and so forth in every combination.

Comment: Did you try *`Esc`*?

Comment: Looking for how to send ESC within VirtualBox in a "vi" editor session in order to give commands, etc.   This is nothing to do with "Ctrl-C" to interrupt a program.

Comment: I didn't say anything about *`CTRL+C`* - I asked if you tried pressing *`Esc`*?

Answer (score 1):

The <kbd>Escape</kbd> key is a shortcut to <kbd>Ctrl+[</kbd>. If the key is missing (as on a *real* vt220, for example), or if it doesn't do what you want (it's been remapped by VirtualBox, or similar), then try the <kbd>Ctrl+[</kbd> combination instead.

Check your VirtualBox setup. It should *not* remap <kbd>Escape</kbd> by default (at least not on the systems I've been using it on).

Answer (score 0):

With a few rare exceptions you can use `Ctrl-C` instead.

Comment: `Ctrl-[` would work better here.  But if OP can't use the Esc key in VirtualBox, there's a deeper problem.